# Saving images to csv file and then reading it from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, python-imaging-library

I have converted images into csv using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 


image_array = []
for name in combined_df['path']:
    image_array.append(np.array(Image.open(name)))

image_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(image_array)     #Then coverted list to dataframe

image_df_1.to_csv('image.csv', index=False) # exported it to csv  (question 1)


csv_df = pd.read_csv('image.csv')  # exported csv using pandas   (question 2)

# I want to see images from csv file but there is problem

np.array(csv_df.iloc[0][0]).shape         # (question 3)
Output: ()      

# but if I see shape of dataframe before saving it to csv

np.array(image_df_1.iloc[0][0]).shape
output: (466, 806, 3)
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong:

1. while saving dataframe into csv file?
2. or while reading csv file?
3. or while converting values to array?

```
# data is available but not able to convert in from of array

csv_df.iloc[0][0]

Output: '[[[180 193 212]\n  [181 194 213]\n  [182 195 214]\n  ...\n  [177 190 209]\n  [177 190 209]\n  [177 190 209]]\n\n [[180 193 212]\n  [181 194 213]\n
```

Please advise.

Comment: Couldn't this be saved as a json file using `image_df_1.to_json('image.csv', index=False)` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

The answer is 1: while saving into csv, the multidimentional DataFrame becomes simple strings. So after reading from csv, the DataFrame cell types become str.
=> The type of `csv_df.iloc[0][0]` is `str` after reading from a csv. but the type of `image_df_1.iloc[0][0]` is `list` (a 3D nested list).

**Long answer:**

This is because when you save a multidimensional DataFrame into csv, the csv becomes a plain text, and then when you read the csv into a new DataFrame, the new DataFrame is not multidimensional, it is simply a 2D DataFrame with string cells.

Thus the type of `csv_df.iloc[0][0]` in your code is a string, but the type of `image_df_1.iloc[0][0]` is a 3D nested list.

So your complete answer is a combination of 1 and 2: it writes string into csv and then reads the string when converting the csv into DataFrame.

Look at my simulation of your code:

```py
>>> image_df_1 = pd.DataFrame([ [ [1, 2], [1, 2] ], [[1, 2], [1, 2] ], [ [1, 2], [1, 2] ], [[1, 2], [1, 2] ] ])  # a multidimensional DataFrame
>>> image_df_1.to_csv('image.csv', index=False)
>>> csv_df = pd.read_csv('image.csv')
>>> csv_df.iloc[0][0]
'[1, 2]'
>>> image_df_1.iloc[0][0]
[1, 2]
>>> type(csv_df.iloc[0][0])
<class 'str'>
>>> type(image_df_1.iloc[0][0])
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

you can see that the type of `csv_df.iloc[0][0]` is `str` and the type of `image_df_1.iloc[0][0]` is `list`.